# Free expansion in vacuum violates quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-states

Gas is known to permeate all space available. Speciﬁcally: if half of a vessel is ﬁlled up with gas and the other half is empty, and the separating wall is removed, the gas molecules will soon ﬁll up both halves of the vessel uniformly. Statistical mechanics explains this by arguing that the macro state in which both halves contain gas is realized by many more micro states than the asymmetric one, therefore it is much more probable.

However, according to quantum mechanics, particles are indistinguishable. So, the state in which only half of the vessel contains gas is only one quantum state, just like the other state when the vessel is uniformly ﬁlled out, as sheer interchange among the particles will not result in a new state. Therefore, the usual argument of statistical physics falls through. Still, despite quantum theory and Pauli’s exclusion principle, our experiences show that gas after all permeates all space available. Why?

Comment: There are not just two states (half and full). Even if the particles are indistinguishable they can be distributed in different energy states that macroscopically looks the same. The correct way to count this in statistical mechanics is explained here (it might be too technical though) http://theory.physics.manchester.ac.uk/~judith/stat_therm/node84.html

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a very simple toy model to illustrate how the combinatorics work out: 
[image: _|_|_|_] two indistinguishable particles, 4 possible positions for them, and an optional wall to put in the middle

What does it mean that the particles are indistinguishable?
Instead of counting two microstates for [image: _|1|_|2] and [image: _|2|_|1] we count just one microstate: [image: _|o|_|o].

All right, so let's count:

- if the particles are confined to just one side: [image: o|o||_|_] = 1 microstate
- if the particles are allowed to spread over the whole volume: [image: o|_|o|_], [image: _|o|o|_], [image: o|_|_|o], [image: _|o|_|o] = 4 microstates<sup>*</sup>

Play with this kind of toy-models on your own, and you will see that the more available positions and particles you have, the stronger the effect: at the number of particles/available positions available for thermodynamical systems, the microstates with all particles on one side become so rare that they will effectively never happen spontaneously in the absence of a wall.

<sub>* Note that, in typical statistical calculations, we would add to those also the 2 microstates with particles confined to either the right or the left side, because technically they are *allowed* by the "non-confined" macrostate (but in practice, when dealing with much larger numbers, these microstates corresponding to more constrained macrostates are negligible anyway).</sub>